# How to use 'history-c' command in a bash script?

Tags: linux, shell

As we know, 'history' command displays the command line history of Linux server and 'history -c' is the command to clear/delete this command line history.

I have to trigger this command through my bash script. Script is as follows,

```
#! /bin/bash
var=`history -c`
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "cleared"
echo $var
fi
```

Output is as follows:

```
  cleared
```

Though its printing "cleared" as the output, history-c is not deleting the history.

It would be great if you can guide/suggest on how i can achieve this, i.e using "history-c" command in my bahs script to delete command line history.Or is there any other way in which i can delete command line history through my bash script.

Thanks & Regards,
Navya

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/546556/how-can-i-use-history-command-in-a-bash-script

Answer (score 3):

`history -c` clears the history for the current shell, and does not delete ~/.bash_history.

But when you run a script the current shell creates a new shell to run the script in and exits that shell when the script is done.

Instead, to execute a script in the current shell you have to source the script. If the name of your script is foo.sh, try running `. ./foo.sh`

But in either case, the script that you've written does not execute the command. Modify it to something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
history -c
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "cleared"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you Nikhil. . ./foo.sh works now :). I would like to use this command in custom operations file of SAP Host Agent, but it throws error. Is there any other way to delete history for root user ? Or any way to include the . ./foo.sh command in operations file? Your help will be appreciated. Thanks & Regards, Navya

Comment: Same a bit shorter: `history -c && echo "cleared"`