# how to clear history of shell that a bash script executed from it in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script in Linux and i want to clear history of shell that my script executed from it.

I know that `history -c` clears current session history, but i want to clear parent session history.

My script is look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# my code

history -c

cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history
```

but it doesn't work!

How can i do this?

Comment: What is the problem after wiping `~/.bash_history` in your script? Doesn't it work? By the way, `cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history` and `> ~/.bash_history` would give you the same result.

Comment: yes @hads0m, it doesn't work!

Comment: Are you running the script with the same user you expect to get its `.bash_history` wiped? Also, have you tried setting an absolute path instead of a relative one?

Comment: Also let me point: as you say _i want to clear history of shell that my script executed from it_ I understand that you are expecting the commands of your script to appear in your user's history? Because that will not be happening.

Comment: i execute my script from root user and i want after finishing script, my root user history be completely clear Including commands before executing my script.

Comment: Well, being `history` a [shell builtin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11454/what-is-the-difference-between-a-builtin-command-and-one-that-is-not) it will not work as intended from inside a script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use 'history-c' command in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126504/how-to-use-history-c-command-in-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

I try this and it works, but after re switch to root user:

```
su - root -c "history -c"
su - root -c "cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history"

history -c
cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history
```